# Deleting the indexes in multidimensional arrays Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

How can I write code that will delete the first index of each row as it is iterating through the rows? Given an array

```
Values = np.array([[100,123,135.3,139.05,156.08,163.88,173.72],
                  [100,123,135.3,139.05,156.08,163.88,173.72],
                  [100,123,135.3,139.05,156.08,163.88,173.72],
                  [100,123,135.3,139.05,156.08,163.88,173.72],
                  [100,123,135.3,139.05,156.08,163.88,173.72],
                  [100,123,135.3,139.05,156.08,163.88,173.72],
                  [100,123,135.3,139.05,156.08,163.88,173.72]])
```

I want the first row to stay `[100,123,135.3,139.05,156.08,163.88,173.72]`, delete the first index from the the next row, making it `[123,135.3,139.05,156.08,163.88,173.72]`, and so on. How can I get the Expected output?

Expected Output:

```
[[100,123,135.3,139.05,156.08,163.88,173.72],
 [123,135.3,139.05,156.08,163.88,173.72],
 [135.3,139.05,156.08,163.88,173.72],
 [139.05,156.08,163.88,173.72],
 [156.08,163.88,173.72],
 [163.88,173.72],
 [173.72]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try list comprehension with enumerate

```
[arr[i:] for i,arr in enumerate(Values.tolist())]

[[100.0, 123.0, 135.3, 139.05, 156.08, 163.88, 173.72],
 [123.0, 135.3, 139.05, 156.08, 163.88, 173.72],
 [135.3, 139.05, 156.08, 163.88, 173.72],
 [139.05, 156.08, 163.88, 173.72],
 [156.08, 163.88, 173.72],
 [163.88, 173.72],
 [173.72]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't exactly do that, since numpy does not support ragged arrays. If you want a ragged array, a list is a better option. Also, it's generally better to think in terms of what you are keeping rather than what you are deleting. What you are looking for is to keep the upper triangle of your matrix.

You can get a flat version of the output in a contiguous array using [`np.triu_indices`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html) and then split it into a list using [`np.split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) based on the locations where the column index changes:

```
v = np.array([100, 123, 135.3, 139.05, 156.08, 163.88, 173.72])
r, c = np.triu_indices(v.size)
np.split(v[c], np.flatnonzero(np.diff(r)) + 1)
```

If your input is a 2D array as shown, you can do a similar thing with just a little more work:

```
value = np.stack((v,) * len(v), axis=0)
r, c = np.triu_indices(value.shape[0])  # Add ..., m=value.shape[1]) if not square
np.split(value[r, c], np.flatnonzero(np.diff(r)) + 1)
```